# Instagram Following Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I am trying to figure out how to get Selenium to click the following section of an Instagram account, here is the html for it.

```
<a class=" _81NM2" href="/peacocktv/following/" tabindex="0"><span class="g47SY lOXF2">219</span> following</a>
```

When using instagram, the direct /username/following link does not actually bring up the following list, you would have to click the field manually on the website for it to appear.

```
log_in = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type = 'submit']"))).click()


not_now = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]')))
not_now.click()


'''not_now2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]')))
not_now2.click()'''


search_select = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder = 'Search']")))
search_select.clear()


'''search_select.send_keys("russwest44", Keys.ENTER)
search_select.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)'''

# Clicks who the person is following:
following = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'following')]")
following.click()
```

Which is the best way to come up with the solution

Comment: Take a look at [instapy](https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy). It has many prebuild functions and just makes life simpler. Also it's very worthy to take a look at their well-organized [documentation](https://instapy.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like couple of issues with your current code:

```
# Clicks who the person is following:
following = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'following')]")
following.click()
```

if you pay attention, you've shared HTML with a tag, so your xpath should be

```
//a[contains(text(),'following')]
```

not

```
//button[contains(text(),'following')]
```

also, you are using `find_elements_by_xpath` it would return a list of web elements. you can not directly trigger `.click` on it.

either switch to `find_element` or

```
following[0].click()
```